The double of the genus two handlebody minus three tori
I am exploring the properties of the manifold $M$ defined as follows. Start with the handlebody $H$ of genus two, whose boundary surface is $\Sigma$. Let $P$ be a pants decomposition of $\Sigma$, where each simple closed curve in $P$ does not bound a disk. If $DH$ represents the double of $H$, the manifold $M$ is defined as the complement of the regular neighborhood of $P$ within $DH$.
Q. Is $M$ well-studied? If yes, where should I start?
If the answer to the above question is negative, how to find the properties of $M$? Here are some randomly selected questions that might be a good starting point.

What is $\pi_1(M)$?
Is $M$ aspherical?
Is $M$ atoroidal?
Is $M$ hyperbolic?


Your manifold $M$ is not well-defined.  This is because you made a non-trivial choice - namely of the pants decomposition $P$.  We could perhaps think of your question as asking about a particular "family" of manifolds.  These manifolds are always aspherical and always geometrically atoroidal.  However, they need not be algebraically atoroidal or hyperbolic.  For example, the "simplest" member of your family is homeomorphic to $S_{0, 3} \times S^1$: the pair of pants crossed with the circle.
A version of your construction has appeared in the literature; see page 790, paragraph 3, of the paper Hyperbolic cone–manifolds with large cone–angles by Juan Souto, who in turn refers to work of Jean–Pierre Otal.

Thank you for your answer! They helped me verify that my interesting manifold is homeomorphic to $S_{0,3} \times S^1$ as in your example. I have added my insight to your answer and organized as follows.
To define $M$, we should take a pants decomposition exactly. The reason is, while some pants decompositions are close to certain meridians, others may be located far from any meridian in terms of the distance of the curve complex. This differences affect the geometry of the manifold $M$.

Meanwhile, for any choice of a pants decomposition, M is aspherical. Let M be considered as a double handlebody marked by the pants decomposition. If M contains an essential sphere disjoint from the pants decomposition, then M can be decomposed into a connected sum of two copies of $S^2 \times S^1$. Because the curves of the pants decomposition are homotopically distinct, there exists a curve of the pants decomposition that bounds a disk. This leads a contradiction. So, there is no essential sphere disjoint from the pants decomposition.

For similar reasons, M is geometrically atoroidal. Suppose there exists an essential torus T in M. Again, consider M as a double handlebody marked by the pants decomposition. Since M is a double handlebody, T contains a simple closed curve that bounds a disc D. Consider the regular neighborhood of the union of T and D. Then one of its boundary components is an essential sphere. By the above, this boundary component must cross the pants decomposition. So, D crosses the pants decomposition. This implies T is parallel to some curve of the pants decomposition. Hence, M is geometrically atoroidal.
